# Azure traffic manager to use custom request header

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

Is it possible to configure Azure Traffic Manager to poll an end point that requires an authorization header? The end point that we have developed for health check has authentication enabled which require credentials to be passed in the request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently **Traffic Manager** can't probe URIs behind authentication walls. That goes for [Basic HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) as well.

i.e. If you're responding with a redirect,

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://token.service
```

Traffic Manager will mark your endpoint **Unhealthy** since it expects a `200 OK` back.

You'll need a page/controller/route/whathaveyou that doesn't require authentication, and returns `200 OK` back to the Traffic Manager probe.

e.g. `http://example.com/health`

Put all your health logic in there - you could for example check if your database and Redis cache is healthy, and then return `200 OK`, else return `5xx`.

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-monitoring/:

> #### Note:

Traffic Manager only considers an endpoint to be online if the return message is 200 OK. An endpoint is unhealthy when any of the following events occur:

> - A non-200 response is received (including a different 2xx code, or a 301/302 redirect)

- Request for client authentication
- Timeout (the timeout threshold is 10 seconds)
- Unable to connect

Comment: Azure Traffic Manager configuration has recently added custom header and Expected Status Code configuration settings. It looks like these can be used to add http headers to the health probe requests. Custom headers can be set both on a global (per traffic manager profile) and on an endpoint level.

Comment: This was GA'ed yesterday. Look for the "Azure Traffic Manager | Custom Header Support in Azure Traffic Manager GA" heading on https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stbnewsbytes/2018/09/24/cloud-platform-release-announcements-for-september-24-2018/.

Comment: It is now also possible to configure which http response codes are considered healthy. (Look for "Azure Traffic Manager | Traffic Manager Custom Health Check Status Codes" in the above link).